# plot an mdscaled matrix of points

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a 151-by-200 matrix, let's say `D`, where rows are patients and cols are some features.

After using [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) and [`mdscale`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mdscale.html) I obtain a 151-by-3 matrix. I also used some consensus clustering algorithm and obtained the partitioning of the patients.

Now I would like to plot the distribution of the mdscaled matrix of points, each one with a shape and a colour (where shapes indicates classes and colors clusters ) as in the image below.

Can you give me an hint on how to do it? Thank you.

[image: plot]

Comment: There are a lot of questions which should give you a good idea how to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091728/k-means-cluster-plot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438080/k-means-plotting-for-3-dimensional-data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006678/creating-legend-for-scatter3-plot-matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to plot grouped 3D points:

```
% data and clusters
load fisheriris
X = meas(:,1:3);
[L,~,Y] = unique(species);

% colors and markers of each group
colors = hsv(numel(L));
markers = 'osdv^x*+.><ph';

% plot
for i=1:numel(L)
    ind = (Y == i);
    h(i) = line(X(ind,1), X(ind,2), X(ind,3), ...
        'LineStyle','none', 'LineWidth',1, 'MarkerSize',8, ...
        'Marker',markers(i), 'Color',colors(i,:), ...
        'MarkerEdgeColor','k', 'MarkerFaceColor',colors(i,:));
end
view(-150,30), axis vis3d, grid on, box on
legend(h, L, 'Location','northeast')
title('MultiDimensional Scaling')
xlabel('dim1'), ylabel('dim2'), zlabel('dim3')
```

[image: plot]

You can customize the shapes and colors to match your criteria ("shapes indicates classes and colors clusters").